# All the jQuery functions that start with X and end with a number

Tags: jquery

**THE CONTEXT**

I have several buttons, each button removes a row from a table. I need a function to delete all the rows in the table. Each row doesnt have a unique ID, it only has the unique number from a array at the end of the function.

**HTML**

```
<a class="delete-row" onclick="remove_parent(1)"></a>
<a class="delete-row" onclick="remove_parent(2)"></a>
<a class="delete-row" onclick="remove_parent(3)"></a>
<a class="delete-row" onclick="remove_parent(4)"></a>
<a class="delete-row" onclick="remove_parent(5)"></a>
```

**WHAT AM I TRYING TO DO**

I want to make a button to remove all the rows from the table. I am trying to de something like this:

```
<a class="delete-row" onclick="remove_parent('+ $('.delete-row')[anyNumber].value +');"></a>
```

How can i execute the function remove_parent that has any number at the end?

**EDIT**

Each row from the table has a lot of data inside, the function remove_parent(...) executes many other functions. For example, when i remove a row it recalculates the sum of all numbers from all the rows. I really have to run the function the way it is but with any number at the end.

Comment: Why not just use `$(this).closest('table').find('tr').remove()`?

Comment: Is the "button" in the table row?  Is there a good reason you can't just fix the HTML to be helpful?

Comment: `$(". delete-row").click()`

Comment: You're overcomplicating this, as j08691 suggested, just make it relative and ditch the numbering completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all links and execute them one by one if you think that's necessary.

Button for removing all rows should call a `remove_all()` function, which can look like this:

```
function remove_all() {
    $('.delete-row').each(function(key){
        remove_parent(key+1);  
    });
}
```

It would be better if each remove link has a number related to it, so you could use that value as a key. For example, link could look like this

```
<a class="delete-row" data-item="1" onclick="remove_parent(1)"></a>
```

and in each iteration you would call `remove_parent($(this).data('item'));`.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
$('yourTableSelector tr').remove();
```